# Нечто по сути как нечто, - знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

*Театр – по сути, как монастырь, живёт отдельной, подчинённой строгим внутренним законам жизнью.*

Можно не объяснять правил; нарисуйте мне, пожалуйста, красиво!

Правлю чужой текст; кроме как "не нравятся мне эти знаки", предложить ничего не получается...

Плакайу.

Возможно ли так (чтобы мысль и акценты остались на местах):

*Театр – по сути как монастырь – живёт отдельной, подчинённой строгим внутренним законам жизнью.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Два варианта, выбор зависит от контекста.**

1)  Театр, по сути, как монастырь: он живёт отдельной, подчинённой строгим внутренним законам жизнью. Сравнение театра с монастырем подробно  объясняется.

2) Ваш вариант: Театр – по сути как монастырь – живёт отдельной, подчинённой строгим внутренним законам жизнью. Вставочная конструкция, попутное замечание.

Comment: А в варианте 1 как объясняются запятые вокруг "по сути"? Менять могу только знаки и неверное словоупотребление, дописывать крайне нежелательно. Шлю варианты автору.

Comment: По сути - вводное слово в (1) и НАРЕЧИЕ в (2). Я не знаю, как Вы относитесь  к интонации , но в (2) вставка читается  в одну фразу, без паузы. Там инверсия (=как монастырь по сути), также можно сказать: Театр – фактически как монастырь – живёт...

Answer (score 1):

Театр – по сути как монастырь, [т.е.] живёт отдельной...

Я бы так поставил. "По сути" не нравится, конечно. Убрать нельзя?

Comment: Спасибо, покажу варианты автору текста.